# Strange results from bitshifting bytes and ints in Java AES implementation

Tags: java, arrays, aes, bit-shift

I'm having trouble making sense of how Java promotes bytes to ints with bitwise operations. I'm attempting to implement AES, and while my output is correct as a 2d byte array, I ultimately need to store it in a 1d int array. However, the following code changes some of the expected values

```
    ciphertexts[0] = ((state[0][0] & 0xFF) << 24) ^ ((state[1][0] & 0xFF) << 16)
                    ^ ((state[2][0] & 0xFF) << 8) ^ state[3][0];
    ciphertexts[1] = ((state[0][1] & 0xFF) << 24) ^ ((state[1][1] & 0xFF) << 16)
                    ^ ((state[2][1] & 0xFF) << 8) ^ state[3][1];
    ciphertexts[2] = ((state[0][2] & 0xFF) << 24) ^ ((state[1][2] & 0xFF) << 16)
                    ^ ((state[2][2] & 0xFF) << 8) ^ state[3][2];
    ciphertexts[3] = ((state[0][3] & 0xFF) << 24) ^ ((state[1][3] & 0xFF) << 16)
                    ^ ((state[2][3] & 0xFF) << 8) ^ state[3][3];
```

I didn't particularly expect masking with 0xFF to help, since the mask should just return the original byte value, but then I tried this:

```
    int zero = ((state[0][0] & 0xFF) << 24);
    int one = ((state[0][1] & 0xFF) << 16);
    int two = ((state[0][2] & 0xFF) << 8) ;
    int three = (state[0][3] & 0xFF);
    int total = zero ^ one ^ two ^ three;

    printhex(zero);
    printhex(one);
    printhex(two);
    printhex(three);
    printhex(total);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
69000000
006A0000
0000D800
00000070
696AD870
```

Which is what I'm trying to do with the code above. Without the masking, the following code gives the following output:

```
    int zero = (state[0][0] << 24);
    int one = (state[0][1] << 16);
    int two = (state[0][2] << 8);
    int three = state[0][3];
    int total = zero ^ one ^ two ^ three;

69000000
006A0000
FFFFD800
00000070
9695D870
```

I also tried what seemed to me more sensible, which is masking after shifting, and got similarly messed up output:

```
    ciphertexts[0] = ((state[0][0] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF) ^ 
        ((state[1][0] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) ^ ((state[2][0] << 8) & 0xFFFF) 
                ^ state[3][0];
    ciphertexts[1] = ((state[0][1] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF) ^ 
        ((state[1][1] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) ^ ((state[2][1] << 8) & 0xFFFF) 
                ^ state[3][1];
    ciphertexts[2] = ((state[0][2] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF) ^ 
        ((state[1][2] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) ^ ((state[2][2] << 8) & 0xFFFF)
                ^ state[3][2];
    ciphertexts[3] = ((state[0][3] << 24) & 0xFFFFFFFF) ^ 
        ((state[1][3] << 16) & 0xFFFFFF) ^ ((state[2][3] << 8) & 0xFFFF)
                ^ state[3][3];
```

Where "messed up" means:

```
ciphertext at round 9 is 963b1fd86a7b04302732488070b4c55a
```

instead of:

```
69C4E0D86A7B0430D8CDB78070B4C55A
```

So my questions are how do I neatly or bytes together into an int, and what is actually going on with the masking and shifting. I looked at other answers and can't figure out why they're not working in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using the xor (`^`) operation rather than a simple bitwise or (`|`)?

Comment: No reason, really. I was toggling between them at one point when I was trying to figure out what was going on, and this was the last state my code was in.

Comment: How is state[][] declared? That odd value, and the fact that anding with 0xFF helps, makes me suspect that the values it contains are undergoing sign extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s the cruelty of a language lacking `unsigned`
(one can get the same result in C if he/she use a `signed char`, ie. signed byte)
Let´s ignore shift´s , only concentrate at the assignment and `&`.
Example value here **0xfe** instead of 0xd8
(the problem will happen with each value between 0x80 and 0xff)

With problem, java:

```
byte a = 0xfe;
int i = a;
```

With problem, C:

```
signed char a = 0xfe;
int i = a;
```

What does happen: A byte can hold value between -128 and +127.
0xfe maps to a negative number (2-complement): **-2**
...and so, i get the value -2 in i, and i is not 8bit, but 32bit long.
According to the rules of the 2-complement, this gives 0xfffffffe
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

So, what does & change, because masking 0xfe first with 0xff
shouldn´t change the value?
Yes, but: As `&` is a "calculation" like `+ -` ...
the value gets **expanded first** to 32bit
(because more suited for the processor´s ALU)

That´s more likely to be known by C/Asm programmers,
but as you see, it´s relevant in Java too.
(if nessecary for an assignment to an smaller variable than 32bit,
it will be shortened again after calculation)

Ie. first, -2=0xfe becomes 32bit -2=0xfffffffe,
then masking results in a 0xfe again (already 32bit)...
which is assigned to i.

Comment: That's the conclusion I just came to.  Good catch.

Comment: Hehe - serves me right: Look after the cat, let it out, return to computer and don't check whether an answer is already there :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your value of `state[0][2]` is a byte `0xD8`. This has the most significant bit set to 1: in binary: `1101 1000`. Before the shift operation `<<` is applied, the `byte` is converted to an `int`. Java doesn't care that byte is unsigned, it is treated as a signed byte. So the byte's most significant bit is filled all the way to the int's most significant bit.

In short: With bytes you need the mask with 0xFF as this masks the filled in bits away in the already converted int.